# bibtex citations in rst2latex

Tags: restructuredtext

Usind **rst2latex**, which command allows me to include a citation key, that references a bibtex database?
In latex I would have achieved this with \cite{Rumpelstielzchen2003}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very handy tool called [bib2reSTcitation](https://github.com/cykustcc/bib2reSTcitation) to convert bibtex style references file to reStructuredText Markup style citation style.

just run:

```
$ python bib2reSTcitation.py -i tex.bib -o references.txt
```

And you get what you want. Hope it helps!

Comment: bib2reSTcitation seems to be a large regular expression that extracts entries from the bibtex file but doesn't really format them as citations; am I misunderstanding what it does?  (for example it seems to write the author list as `A and B and C and D`, just like in bibTeX, and it doesn't seem to let you pick a citation style.

Answer (score 12):

The solution I found is inlineing latex into the rst document:

```
.. role:: raw-tex(raw)
    :format: latex html

Introduction
============
A profit maximizing agent in an environment with a finite number of buyers
following :raw-tex:`\cite{Kutschinski2003}` investigates price setting by 
reinforcement learning agent.

# at the end of the document
.. raw:: latex

    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{/home/path/library}
```

The role definition at the beginning of the text allows us to put pure latex 
inline. With :raw-tex:`\cite{Kutschinski2003}` we index a latex reference
from the bibtex file. At the end of the document we put a raw latex paragraph, started with
.. raw: latex that references the library.bib file. (as created by bibtex or mendeley)
The rst file can be compiled with:

```
rst2latex paper.rst > build/paper.tex && cd build/ && latex paper.tex && bibtex paper.aux && latex paper.tex && pdflatex paper.tex && evince paper.pdf & cd ..
```

Or create a paper.sh file with following compilation command:

```
rst2latex paper.rst > build/paper.tex 
cd build/
latex paper.tex
bibtex paper.aux
latex paper.tex
pdflatex paper.tex
evince paper.pdf
cd ..
```

(if latex causes trouble with pictures substitute it with pdflatex)

Answer (score 12):

Another way (though also LaTeX specific) is to make it nicer in editing.

```
.. role:: cite

.. raw:: latex

   \providecommand*\DUrolecite[1]{\cite{#1}}
```

This way you can use

```
:cite:`key`
```

And also at the end of your document:

```
.. raw:: latex

   \bibliographystyle{plain}
   \bibliography{/home/path/library}
```

Comment: Would that be in combination with my solution or how does it find the library?

Comment: The same as in your solution. I added it to the answer for completeness.